# Как получить и отобразить в textView размер списка LiveData<List<>>?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, livedata

я только начал учить Android и Kotlin, пытаюсь написать приложение с использованием Room, с большой, предзаписанной базой данных. Нужно получить и отобразить в  textView количество объектов БД с определенными значениями полей. Список получаю в формате LiveData<List>. Можно ли отобразить размер списка LiveData<List> в textView во фрагменте?

```
@Dao
interface WordsDao {

    @Update
    suspend fun updateStatus(wordEntity: WordEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM wordsDB WHERE word_block = :block AND word_status = :status")
    fun getByStatus(block: Int, status: Int): LiveData<List<WordEntity>>
}
```

```
class WordsRepository (private val wordsDAO: WordsDao){

    val getByStatus10 = getByStatus(1,0)
    

    suspend fun updateStatus(wordEntity: WordEntity){
        wordsDAO.updateStatus(wordEntity)
    }

    fun getByStatus (block: Int, status: Int):
            LiveData<List<WordEntity>> {
        return wordsDAO.getByStatus(block, status)
    }
}
```

```
class WordViewModel (private val wordsRepository: WordsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val getByStatusF2 = wordsRepository.getByStatus10
    
    
    fun updateStatus(wordEntity: WordEntity) = viewModelScope.launch{

        wordsRepository.updateStatus(wordEntity)
    }
```

Comment: прикладывайте, пожалуйста, ваш код.

Comment: Не нужно перекладывать список по переменным - выводите в `TextView`, обновляйте адаптер или что ещё нужно прямо в обсервере, подписываться соответственно нужно когда UI создан.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53273752/12191177

Comment: IR42, спасибо, работает